# Regarding favoring composition over inheritance approch, STRATEGY pattern

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, composition, strategy-pattern

I was ask an question in an interview that was lets say there's the class A with a method drawShape() and there's an another class B with the method drawSquare(). Now there's a third class C. In my class C I want both of these methods of class A and B. How do I get both of them at same time?

For this I came up with the following approach:
Java doesn't support multiple Class inheritance:

```
Class.interface IA {
   void drawshape();
}

inerface IB {
   void drawsquare();
}

class A implements IA {
    ...
}

class B implements IB {
    ...
}

class C implements IA, IB {
   private A a;
   private B b;

   void drawshape() {
     a.drawshape()
   } 

   void drawsquare() {
     b. drawsquare()
   }
}
```

The shown approach is based on the principle of favor composition over inheritance. Please let me know if it's the correct approach. This pattern is also known as the strategy pattern, please advise it is correct or approach that I am following. guys any more comments regarding this approach please advise, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, composition is probably the best approach in this case. 
In some cases you may want to inherit from one class and use composition on the other(s).